# Jenkins build parameter not working in quotes

Tags: jenkins, docker

I'm trying to issue a jenkins shell command with docker looks like this:

docker run -v ${env.param1}:/workspace --privileged=true app sh -c 'python app.py --option ${env.param1}'

...and the result looks like this:

docker run -v actual.param1:/workspace --privileged=true app sh -c 'cd folder && python app.py --option ${env.param2}'

The first environment parameter ${env.param1} is successfully replaced with actual parameter, but the second one ${env.param2} is not. Seems to me that because the second ${env.param2} is inside a single quote, jenkins is not replacing the parameter.

Thank you for reading and I would appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> docker run -v ${env.param1}:/workspace --privileged=true app sh -c 'python app.py --option ${env.param1}'

You are passing `${env.param1}` inside of `'`'s (single quotes), therefore it is not being evauluated, change your command to use doublequotes instead:

> docker run -v ${env.param1}:/workspace --privileged=true app sh -c "python app.py --option ${env.param1}"